# np.divide Making Entire Vector Nan

Tags: python, numpy

I am using `np.divide` to divide two vectors. The numerator has all floats and the denominator is a mix of nice sized floats, extremely small floats, and np.inf. The resulting vector has a `np.nan` in every place, even though only a handful of entries should have that. How can I fix this to have `np.nan` where appropriate and floats everywhere else?

Comment: Can you add the numpy variables in your question?

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of the code?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
np.true_divide(A, B, where=(A!=0) | (B!=0))
```

or

```
C = A / B          # may print warnings, suppress them with np.seterrstate if you want
C[np.isnan(C)] = 0
```